# Shall QA team share their Test Cases with Dev Team?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, qa

I am building the test process for my development team.

Currently, we have multiple ping-pong scenarios between Dev and Test teams.

to send the product to QA then QA find issues and return them to developers then fix them to QA and so on.

I asked the Test team to share the Test Cases they have with the developers and they seem ok with that.

I wonder if this is the right approach to do tests from the development side as they may just rely on the tester to provide them with the test cases and we get even worse quality till QA tells us how exactly to test.

I saw this question for the other way around where Dev shares their test cases with the QA,

[Sharing development test cases (unit and development integration) with the QA (test) team?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263753/sharing-development-test-cases-unit-and-development-integration-with-the-qa-t)

My question is the QA to share their work with Dev

Comment: "they [developers] may just rely on the tester to provide them with the test cases and we get even worse quality till QA tells us how exactly to test."  Can you explain this? I do not understand the reasoning.

Comment: There is no such thing as "QA test cases" and "Dev test cases". This kind of thinking is indicative of organizational dysfunction that treats QA as separate function from Dev. There should be only one team responsible for development and maintenance of the software. And that one team should have only single test suite where every member, irrespective of role or function has input and can run it to verify stability of the software.

Comment: IMHO [Sharing development test cases (unit and development integration) with the QA (test) team?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263753/sharing-development-test-cases-unit-and-development-integration-with-the-qa-t) is similar enough for a close vote as "duplicate". I recommend to read [my answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/263754) to that question, it is not just about sharing test cases in one direction.

Comment: What about the acceptance criteria against which the software is measured?  A developer should know this before they write any code, but acceptance criteria are something for the business to provide as part of the requirements before a developer estimates it or picks it up to start work.    It sounds like you're suggesting that the QA testers would provide the acceptance criteria, which sounds like QA testers defining requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developers should be able to accurately develop at the same time the QA testers are writing tests. Writing test cases should not rely on writing code. Writing code should not rely on writing test cases. Ideally the requirements should be clear enough that developers will write code at the same time testers write test cases. It is all based on requirements.

The true problem seems to be that testers are getting what appears to be bad quality code. There could be a number of underlying problems. If developers cannot give testers working code without knowing the test cases ahead of time, then it seems like the requirements need to be reviewed by the team before starting work. That is their chance to ask questions and gain a shared understanding of the feature.

Both developers and testers should fully understand what is being built before writing code or tests.